# How to Serialize Json Array to an Array to be used in Android Studio

Tags: android, arrays, json, asp.net-web-api, retrofit

How do I serialize a Json Array like the the picture I am going to upload? Sorry If this question may be repetitive but I cannot figure out how to do it in my use case.

For more context here are some photos. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OECv9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `Retrofit`, so it has to do it automatically. Just change return type to:

```
Call<List<petProfile>>
```

If your Retrofit is not doing it, add ->

```
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

after `Retrofit.Builder()`

Comment: Thaks for the swift reply, i already aded ConverterFactory. By return type do you mean in my POJO statements or like how I did it in this picture? Thanks https://imgur.com/a/ylIrRXu

Comment: Update: I already have the json array in an ArrayList, do you have any sources that I can learn from so I can use this ArrayList to a Autocomplete Text View? Thanks!

Comment: @Sentinel927 I've never used it but here's a [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) with a snippet:

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of libs handling serialize and deserialize json.
such as Gson and JsonSlurpper.

Here you can see the Gson example:

```
    new Gson().toJson(/*place your POJO here*/); // serialize
    new Gson().fromJson(/*json object*/, /*class to convert to*/); //deserialize
```

Comment: Update: I currently have my json array in an arrayList and is now figuring out how can I use a specific column or whatever you call it in my array list and use that as keywords in a AutoComplete Text View. Do you have any sources on this? Picure of my arrayList https://imgur.com/a/MK93CI1   Thanks!